# Upload and Store Image File in Database with description using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, image-uploading

I have been trying to uload image to a datebase with descriptionof the image and then get the data off the database and put the description uder the image i am new to php i cant find info the internet i have the uploaded to the datebase and displaying i just cant get the descriptiono working thanks for the help

index.php

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select Image File to Upload:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <br><input type="text" name="description" placeholder="description of        your image"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

upload.php

```
    // Create database connection
    $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

    // Check connection
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }
    $statusMsg = '';

    // File upload path
    $targetDir = "upload/";
    $fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
    $fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
        // Allow certain file formats
        $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');
        if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
            // Upload file to server
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
                // Insert image file name into database
                $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
                if($insert){
                    $statusMsg = "The file ".$fileName. " has been uploaded successfully.";
                }else{
                    $statusMsg = "File upload failed, please try again.";
                }
            }else{
                $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }else{
            $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, GIF, & PDF files are allowed to upload.';
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
    }

    // Display status message
    echo $statusMsg;
    ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is not saving the `description` to the database. That's why you can't show it.

First you need to add a new column `description` inside table `images`.

After that, you must get the description sent in the request, as you did with `$fileName`

```
$description = $_POST['description'];
```

You can now insert into `images`:

```
$insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images (file_name, description, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', '".$description."', NOW())");
```

Comment: `$_GET` should be `$_POST`, I would have edited it but the SQL Injection issue needs addressing, and perhaps rewritten so the OP does it right, else next question will be why cant I add description `In this image, I'm watching football`

Comment: Thanks for finding my error, @LawrenceCherone. I too believe his code can be improved in a lot of ways: style, security, etc. I did not address the additional issues in my response to avoid the long and broad answer I don't have time to write right now. Besides that, I believe  that delivering a lot of information to someone who is struggling with a basic issue like he is, will bring more confusion than benefits.

Comment: thansk for the help i have try it and this is what i get **Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\upload.php on line 15**

Comment: @Caconde sorry i had put extra squrl bracket in sorry i am a littel confused about **$description = $_POST['description'];** because where ever i put in in come up as  **Notice: Undefined index: description in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\upload.php on line 12** thanks for the help

Comment: Weird. Check your form inside `index.php`, please. The field must have the property `name="description"`

Comment: @Caconde thanks i must have got the spelling worng it working now thanks